# Why is Possible Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable warning *not* shown

Tags: c#, resharper, ienumerable

I am a bit puzzled why **doesn't** Resharper (nor Studio, or FX Cop:) ) warn me agains possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable in the code below:

```
//warning here fine
 IEnumerable<IFileWrapper> filteredCollection = ctaWrappersContainer.FileContainer.Files.Where(x=>x.IsArchiveEntry);
int y1 = filteredCollection.Count();
int y2 = filteredCollection.Count();

//why no warning here?
int countOfIenumerable = ctaWrappersContainer.FileContainer.Files.Count();
int countOfIenumerableAgain = ctaWrappersContainer.FileContainer.Files.Count();
```

The Files collection is a true IEnumerable that will reevaluate with each call.
Here's how the Files property gets assigned somewhere in code:

`container.Files = this.GetFilesFromArchive(container, zipFile.FullName, searchPattern);`

and the `GetFilesFromArchive()` is enumerating entries and returning them one by one (based on some filter). **So, each time I call the count, it does that again (as expected)**

```
 protected override IEnumerable<IFileWrapper> GetFilesFromArchive(FileContainer fileContainer, string zipFilePath, string searchPattern)
        {
           //do some filtering magic on a collection of entries in a zip
          yield return new ZipEntryWrapper(fileContainer, zipEntry, zipFile);
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't know that `FileContainer.Files` returns the same `IEnumerable<T>` each time it's accessed. There's the possibility that it creates a new `IEnumerable<T>` in its getter. Blindly adding this warning would probably produce lots of false positives.

Comment: Can you post the code rather than an image? Many people (myself included) cannot view external images due to firewall restrictions.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - sorry, was not aware of that!

Comment: In addition, images don't google well. We very much like code and error msgs as text here.

Comment: It doesn't warn you for the same reason that it doesn't warn you if you call `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` twice - because as far as it knows, that's giving you two separate enumerables. So I agree with /u/canton7's thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL/DR**: I agree with @**canton7**, it would result in too many false positives. Just don't put expensive enumerables in properties, it's a bad practice.

Long version:

**Cannot tell if enumeration is expensive or not**
Basically, the inspection about possible multiple enumeration tries to warn you about potential performance problems, because very often `IEnumerable` comes from expensive calculations like database queries. But ReSharper cannot tell for sure if enumeration is really expensive or not, because tracing all enumerables' origin would be very complex and very slow, and in some cases impossible (enumerable coming from interface or virtual method in a class library, and overrides could be in external code).

**Enumerable properties are often used to encapsulate simple collections**
This also applies to enumerable properties: ReSharper cannot be sure if that enumerable has expensive enumeration or not. If it would still go ahead and warn about multiple enumerations of the same enumerable property, it would result in too many false positives, because many programmers don't put expensive enumerables in properties. Most often, enumerable properties return basic collections like List or HashSet under the hood, and return type `IEnumerable` is chosen to encapsulate implementation details and allow developer to change implementing collection to something else later. Although now we have `IReadOnlyCollection` which is better for such encapsulation, still we have tons of old code with `IEnumerable`.

**Properties are meant to be lightweight, don't put expensive calculations there**
I would go further and argue that even if ReSharper could warn you about expensive multiple enumeration on properties, it would still be a bad practice for properties to return expensive enumerable. Even if you would have no single method which enumerates twice on such property, you could still have a complex method that would call different enumerating methods several times in a row. And your teammates won't even think about caching access to enumeration results in such cases, because properties are meant to be lightweight and there is no sense in caching them in almost every case.